# Packaging Google Chrome and Flash into a Linux Distro?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, chrome, adobe-flash

I've been working on a Linux distro based on Arch, and I want to include Google Chrome and Adobe's Flash Plugin.

Can I get in trouble with Google or Adobe if I pre-install both of those pieces of software into a Linux distro which I plan to release within the upcoming month?

Comment: Read the licenses, and ask a lawyer?

Comment: Well, it's 6400 words for Chrome, but I can't speak in Lawyer...

Comment: If you can't speak in lawyer, I don't think we can really do it for you..... if you need someone to speak in Unix/Linux geek, this is the place.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe's terms are that you must apply for a license to distribute their products:

> Adobe provides a free license to allow you to redistribute Adobe Flash® Player or Adobe Shockwave® Player on your company's intranet, or with your software product or service.

http://www.adobe.com/licensing/

You have to supply them details of your intended distribution, including information about your licensing, number of end users etc.

The relevant part of the Chrome license looks to be this clause:

> 9.3 Subject to section 1.2, unless Google has given you specific written permission to do so, you may not assign (or grant a sub-license of) your rights to use the Software, grant a security interest in or over your rights to use the Software, or otherwise transfer any part of your rights to use the Software.

Which suggests that, as long as you do not change the original license, you will not infringe.

**Note**: this does *not* constitute legal advice...

Comment: Okay, thanks. I read the agreement for Chrome too, and in `(2)`, it said that by using the product, you agree with the license automagically.

Comment: I'll try and contact Adobe, but to play it safe, I'll include both EULAs into the Chrome launcher.

Comment: Re Chrome: yes, that's a standard clause. The important thing to make clear is that in packaging it, you are not in any way changing those rights.